# Printing Names using for loop

Tags: python, tuples

[image]

```
president = [('D. Trump',2017), ('Barack Obama',2009), ('B. Clinton',1993), 
             ('George W. Bush',2001)]

max_w = president[0][1]
min_w = president[0][1]

for word in president:

    if word[1] > max_w:
        max_w = word
    elif word[1] < min_w:
        min_w = word   

print(max_w, min_w)
```

why the max_w and min_w is a tuple? should it be a int??

Comment: Use `max_w = word[1]` and `min_w = word[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `max_w = word[1]` and `min_w = word[1]` within those conditionals.

Alternatively, you could write this:

```py
for name, year in president:
    if year > max_w:
        max_w = year
    if year < min_w:
        min_w = year
```

Or save the initialization and do this (even better IMO):

```py
max_w = max(year for name, year in president)
min_w = min(year for name, year in president)
```